# How to 'docker plugin install' for json-based plugin

Tags: java, spring, docker

I'm working on a brand new volume plugin and I'm required all of [vol-test](https://github.com/docker/vol-test) tests to be passed. And I have all tests successfully passed (on an environment with installed plugin) except the first one, which is `docker plugin install`. The thing is that there are [three](http://dockerdocs.gclearning.cn/engine/extend/plugin_api/) possible ways one can install a custom plugin:

> .sock files are UNIX domain sockets.
>   .spec files are text files containing a URL, such as unix:///other.sock or tcp://localhost:8080.
>   .json files are text files containing a full json specification for
>    the plugin.

and we use json, which is simply a REST server implementing docker API (written in java, spring). The installation process for it straight forward: just copy the json file in `/etc/docker/plugins` and dockerd automatically discovers it.
The problem comes when I try to integrate the plugin into `docker plugin install` command. As it stated [here](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/reference/commandline/plugin_install/#extended-description):

> Docker looks first for the plugin on your Docker host. If the plugin does not exist locally, then the plugin is pulled from the registry.

Our installation process doesn't assume a connection to a private or public registry, so we need first `docker plugin create` command in order to create the plugin locally. And this is where I'm having hard time to wrap my head around how to do that with json-based plugin. As per [this](http://dockerdocs.gclearning.cn/engine/extend/#creating-the-plugin) doc, I need to specify a path to the plugin. If I use a directory name it expects `config.json` and `rootfs` to be present in the directory.

BUT
1. `config.json` - this is a config, that describes `.sock` format configs, and not the `.json` format (please correct me if I'm wrong)
2. how do I create the rootfs and why do I need it if my plugin is just a standalone REST service and it is not even in the container?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score -1):

> > config.json - this is a config, that describes .sock format configs, and not the .json format (please correct me if I'm wrong)

I've verified it working with .spec files, not very sure how it works with json files though. For .spec files, you don't mention .spec files in config.json. That is used only for unix socket plugins (option 1). Infact there is no need to have config.json for TCP socket plugins.

> > how do I create the rootfs and why do I need it if my plugin is just a standalone REST service and it is not even in the container?

In my understanding, rootfs is only for unix socket plugins. Plugin discovery works out of the box if .spec files exists in the right folder. In nutshell, you just create spec file and put it in the right discovery folder and try to bootstrap the container with that plugin name. You don't have to run commands like "docker plugin create/install/enable". You run the server, put the file in right folder and let new containers use that plugin.